# What's a transfer transaction having the same sender and receiver addresses?

Tags: transactions, transfer, wallet-transfer

I'm currently searching for transactions happening on a set of addresses on BSC network and i found the following transaction: [0xc6d3fc6a28abdc51341cf765e4a3a9879e032ff271047cd32e9ecd86c1733522](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc6d3fc6a28abdc51341cf765e4a3a9879e032ff271047cd32e9ecd86c1733522)

What's the purpose of this BNB transaction (although it's a Zero value): is it accountable ? (the receiving address balance is credited in case it was not a zero-value transaction ?)
Is it possible to have the same case in BEP-20 transfer()'s ?

Comment: I hope that this thread is helpful for understand this type of transaction: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91328/explain-self-transactions-and-fees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "self-transfer" transactions to cancel a pending transaction. This is how Metamask does it by the way.

Basically to cancel a pending transaction all you have to do is make another transaction with same nonce and higher gas price. So the second tx gets included, and the first becomes invalid. The "self-transfer" is simply the easiest tx you can make, and it doesn't have any side-effects.

If you notice, the gasPrice of the transaction you linked is 5.55 gwei, compared to the usual 5 gwei of the other transactions around that one. This confirms that they had a transaction they wanted to cancel this way.

Comment: Is it then safe to just ignore these when monitoring incoming funds on an address ? same goes for smart contracts using the transfer() function ?

Comment: You can ignore txs if the "from" and "to" are the same address. Generally there shouldn't be any smart contract involved in these kind of transactions, so if you find one with those there may be other reasons.